# How to Setup Magento Stores with Different Domain

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, catalog, store-view, base-url

I would like to know if it is possible, and more importantly, the correct approach, to use a single Magento instance/server to host the following two websites:

- two magento ecommerce 'websites'
- different product catalogue
- different 'branding' for each
- same payment methods
- different paypal payment account
- different customer base
- different domain/URL
- different email templates for each
- same theme, but different color variation
- same checkout workflow
- same language
- same currency

I am thinking in terms of maintenance of the code base and not having multiple logins for all admin/coding sytems..
However, I am also cautious about not making a single instance over complicated.

Once each site gets a larger customer base and more orders, I may split the two, however for now, I would like to keep things simple...but correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to achieve this.

Please follow steps mentioned on following blog

https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

Hope it helps you